# Change colour of colour markers in leaflet map based on selectInput in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

Here's a small slice of a dataset I'm working on

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(nestbox = c("B1", "B10", "B100", "B101", "B102", 
"B103", "B104", "B105", "B106", "B107", "B108", "B109", "B11", 
"B110", "B111", "B112", "B113", "B114", "B115", "B116", "B117", 
"B118", "B119", "B12", "B121", "B122", "B123", "B124", "B125", 
"B126", "B127", "B128", "B129", "B13", "B130", "B131", "B133", 
"B134", "B136", "B137", "B138", "B139", "B14", "B140", "B141", 
"B142", "B142A", "B143", "B144", "B145", "B146", "B147", "B148", 
"B149", "B15", "B150", "B151", "B152", "B153", "B154", "B155", 
"B156", "B157", "B158", "B159", "B16", "B160", "B161", "B162", 
"B163", "B164", "B165", "B166", "B168", "B169", "B170", "B170A", 
"B171", "B172", "B173", "B174", "B175", "B176", "B177", "B178", 
"B179", "B18", "B180", "B181", "B182", "B183", "B184", "B185", 
"B186", "B187", "B188", "B189", "B190", "B191", "B192"), Longitude = c(-1.308809725, 
-1.309306062, -1.308591288, -1.308725397, -1.308453941, -1.30826971, 
-1.308223849, -1.308510734, -1.308774826, -1.309100942, -1.308661051, 
-1.308788844, -1.309505208, -1.3091438, -1.309487017, -1.309235075, 
-1.309665645, -1.308965346, -1.308648633, -1.307965425, -1.308046729, 
-1.307626664, -1.307029421, -1.309264223, -1.306229451, -1.307167439, 
-1.307846954, -1.308184483, -1.308361108, -1.308712982, -1.309586205, 
-1.309736174, -1.309967322, -1.30988614, -1.310144073, -1.310207229, 
-1.310332327, -1.310248542, -1.310671738, -1.311271535, -1.31180421, 
-1.311607541, -1.309055439, -1.312474199, -1.312743518, -1.313056542, 
-1.312898665, -1.312619555, -1.313038098, -1.312717702, -1.312295745, 
-1.312181745, -1.311711673, -1.311154382, -1.308580716, -1.311484218, 
-1.310989254, -1.311770452, -1.312408125, -1.312575426, -1.313220318, 
-1.312965409, -1.312799476, -1.31262028, -1.313393272, -1.308310566, 
-1.313737475, -1.314102982, -1.314181557, -1.313547026, -1.313998781, 
-1.313728937, -1.313688331, -1.313176409, -1.312907533, -1.312311175, 
-1.312342883, -1.31196085, -1.311368997, -1.309571159, -1.310019078, 
-1.309446474, -1.310651343, -1.311742706, -1.312701894, -1.313811195, 
-1.307353423, -1.313373501, -1.312720774, -1.312125596, -1.312104413, 
-1.311495968, -1.311081217, -1.31002069, -1.309428424, -1.309651304, 
-1.309355735, -1.308883116, -1.309512252, -1.308438024), Latitude = c(51.76481187, 
51.76457202, 51.76488251, 51.76464054, 51.76438764, 51.76411637, 
51.76370376, 51.76351538, 51.76330114, 51.76375109, 51.76410968, 
51.76428126, 51.76481595, 51.76475988, 51.76505861, 51.76542577, 
51.76569803, 51.76600861, 51.76587188, 51.76601172, 51.76638084, 
51.76636938, 51.76657266, 51.76544329, 51.76676575, 51.76702303, 
51.76712594, 51.76684919, 51.76667041, 51.76640274, 51.76615612, 
51.76582432, 51.76587064, 51.76549253, 51.76568286, 51.76534201, 
51.76473989, 51.7645326, 51.76433727, 51.76396316, 51.76419105, 
51.76365969, 51.76580234, 51.76351641, 51.76340532, 51.76378478, 
51.76368495, 51.76393508, 51.76404542, 51.76415144, 51.76426586, 
51.76413932, 51.76455915, 51.76499646, 51.76557477, 51.76522317, 
51.76537312, 51.76545862, 51.76545336, 51.76493284, 51.76445109, 
51.76501604, 51.76544665, 51.76579626, 51.76592665, 51.76618459, 
51.76570388, 51.76549023, 51.76508608, 51.76488457, 51.76471637, 
51.76435515, 51.7641661, 51.76352474, 51.76310058, 51.76324994, 
51.7630703, 51.76341873, 51.7632714, 51.76334178, 51.76342533, 
51.76391649, 51.76567684, 51.7663306, 51.7661474, 51.76657646, 
51.7662329, 51.76677171, 51.76681285, 51.7668813, 51.76732175, 
51.7673092, 51.76790019, 51.76807379, 51.76829204, 51.76853917, 
51.76891506, 51.76949672, 51.7691048, 51.76922436), Species = c("Empty", 
"Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Great tit", "Empty", "Empty", "Great tit", 
"Empty", "Empty", "Blue tit", "Empty", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", 
"Empty", "Blue tit", "Empty", "Empty", "Empty", "Empty", "Great tit", 
"Empty", "Great tit", "Empty", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", 
"Blue tit", "Empty", "Blue tit", "Empty", "Empty", "Empty", "Great tit", 
"Empty", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Empty", "Blue tit", 
"Empty", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Empty", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", 
"Blue tit", "Empty", "Empty", "Empty", "Empty", "Empty", "Blue tit", 
"Empty", "Blue tit", "Empty", "Great tit", "Blue tit", "Empty", 
"Blue tit", "Empty", "Empty", "Empty", "Blue tit", "Empty", "Empty", 
"Empty", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Empty", "Great tit", "Blue tit", 
"Blue tit", "Nuthatch", "Blue tit", "Great tit", "Empty", "Blue tit", 
"Great tit", "Empty", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Great tit", "Blue tit", 
"Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Empty", "Empty", "Blue tit", "Empty", 
"Empty", "Blue tit", "Empty", "Blue tit", "Empty", "Empty", "Great tit", 
"Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Blue tit", "Empty")), row.names = c(NA, 
100L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to make a shiny dashboard with the rest of the data and want a leaflet map output with an input selection box on the side, which displays species but I want them to display in different colours.
I've tried making a colour palette with

```
df$Species<- as.factor(df$Species)
spcol<-colorFactor(palette = "viridis", df$Species)
```

Then adding a colour argument to addCircles or addCircleMarkers but this gives an error

> 

Error:no applicable method for 'metaData' applied to an object of class "NULL"

So my question is how can I add different colours for different species to my map? Full code here works if I remove the colour argument in addCircles or addCircleMarkers

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)





#colour palette for the map
df$Species<- as.factor(df$Species)
spcol<-colorFactor(palette = "viridis", df$Species)

ui <- (fluidPage(
                 title ="Map of Wytham",
                 sidebarLayout(
                   sidebarPanel(
                     selectInput("Species", label = "Species", choices = c(df$Species), selected = "Great tit")
                   ),
                   mainPanel(
                     leafletOutput("NestMap", width = "700px", height = "700px"))
                 )
))

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$NestMap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% 
      setView(lng = -1.324640, lat = 51.770462, zoom = 14) %>%
      addCircleMarkers(lng = df$Longitude, lat = df$Latitude, color = ~spcol(Species), radius = 8, popup = df$nestbox)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$Species, {
    
    if(input$Species != "")
    {
      leafletProxy("NestMap") %>% clearShapes()
      index = which(df$Species == input$Species)
      leafletProxy("NestMap")%>%  addCircleMarkers(lng = df$Longitude[index], lat = df$Latitude[index],color = ~spcol(Species),
                                            radius = 8, popup = df$nestbox[index])
    }
  }) 
}





# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Try using `color = spcol(df$Species)`

Comment: no get a different error now : "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"

Comment: I tried your code and I do not get that error. Did you change both occurences of color? Also, this might help you pin down what's going wrong: `options(shiny.fullstacktrace=TRUE)`

Comment: Actually forgot to change the df name, I have a different name in my script! But now I have different problem, the map just keeps drawing layer on top of layer, whereas the old code without colour argument would clear after each input?

Comment: Just added clearMarkers() to the leafletProxy arguement

Comment: yeah, should do the trick :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to some help from @Vvdl in the comments I have the working code.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)





#colour palette for the map
df$Species<- as.factor(df$Species)
spcol<-colorFactor(palette = "viridis", df$Species)

ui <- (fluidPage(
                 title ="Map of Wytham",
                 sidebarLayout(
                   sidebarPanel(
                     selectInput("Species", label = "Species", choices = c(df$Species), selected = "Great tit")
                   ),
                   mainPanel(
                     leafletOutput("NestMap", width = "700px", height = "700px"))
                 )
))

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$NestMap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% 
      setView(lng = -1.324640, lat = 51.770462, zoom = 14) %>%
      addCircleMarkers(lng = df$Longitude, lat = df$Latitude, color = spcol(df$Species), radius = 8, popup = df$nestbox)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$Species, {
    
    if(input$Species != "")
    {
      leafletProxy("NestMap") %>% clearShapes() %>% clearMarkers()
      index = which(df$Species == input$Species)
      leafletProxy("NestMap")%>%  addCircleMarkers(lng = df$Longitude[index], lat = df$Latitude[index],color = spcol(df$Species[index]),
                                            radius = 8, popup = df$nestbox[index])
    }
  }) 
}





# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```